# How to solve "Active: activating (auto-restart)" when starting collectd.service?

Tags: bash, fedora, systemd

I have problem with starting **collectd.serivce** in my Fedora 31 64-bit OS which I've installed via `sudo dnf install collectd` command. When I type `sudo systemctl status collectd.service` I get following output:

```bsh
    ● collectd.service - statistics collection daemon
       Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/collectd.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
       Active: activating (auto-restart) since Sat 2020-09-19 18:18:47 CEST; 3s ago
         Docs: man:collectd(1)
      Process: 3796 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/collectd (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
     Main PID: 3796 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
          CPU: 7ms
```

BTW, I've had to manually create `collectd.service` file which is located in */etc/systemd/system/* directory. What is really weird is I keep receiving **activating (auto-restart)** **status=0/SUCCESS** in above mentioned output. I also performed following commands in respective order:

1. `sudo systemctl daemon-reload`
2. `sudo systemctl stop collectd.service`
3. `sudo systemctl start collectd.service`

...but nothing changed and I've tried restarting my computer after all that and performing all mentioned 1)-3) steps and nothing helped.  BTW, this is my `collectd.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=statistics collection daemon
Documentation=man:collectd(1)
After=local-fs.target network.target
Requires=local-fs.target network.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/collectd
Restart=always
RestartSec=10
StandardOutput=syslog
StandardError=syslog

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

This is how my `/etc/collectd.conf` file looks like:

```
#
# Config file for collectd(1).
# Please read collectd.conf(5) for a list of options.
# http://collectd.org/
#

##############################################################################
# Global                                                                     #
#----------------------------------------------------------------------------#
# Global settings for the daemon.                                            #
##############################################################################

#Hostname    "localhost"
FQDNLookup   true
#BaseDir     "/var/lib/collectd"
#PIDFile     "/var/run/collectd.pid"
PluginDir   "/usr/lib64/collectd"
TypesDB     "/usr/share/collectd/types.db"

LoadPlugin cpu

<Plugin cpu>
  ReportByCpu false
  ReportByState false
#  Interval 1
  ValuesPercentage true
#  ReportNumCpu false
#  ReportGuestState false
#  SubtractGuestState true
</Plugin>

<Plugin memory>
        ValuesAbsolute false
        ValuesPercentage true
</Plugin>

Include "/etc/collectd.d"
LoadPlugin syslog
LoadPlugin logfile
#LoadPlugin log_logstash

<Plugin logfile>
        LogLevel info
        File "/var/log/error_syslog"
        Timestamp true
#       PrintSeverity false
</Plugin>

#<Plugin log_logstash>
#       LogLevel info
#       File "/var/log/collectd.json.log"
#</Plugin>

<Plugin syslog>
        LogLevel info
</Plugin>
Include "/etc/collectd.d"
```

Any suggestion/pointing me in right direction how to solve this problem is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[As the `collectd` manual tells you](https://collectd.org/documentation/manpages/collectd.1.shtml), you must either use the `-f` command-line option and `Type=simple` or use `Type=notify` (and no `-f`) in a service unit.
[The sample service unit that comes with collectd](https://github.com/collectd/collectd/blob/master/contrib/systemd.collectd.service) does this.

Comment: Hi @JdeBP, thank you for suggestion. Unfortunately **sample** service unit **did NOT come** with `collectd` installation, so I had to create it manually. Also `Type` property I presume you are reffering to `collectd.service` file, but where should I place it - which section (`Unit`, `Service` or some other)? Could you please update your answer with example? Thank you.

Comment: Turns out after I've added `Interval` property in `cpu` plugin in my `/etc/collectd.conf` file by following instructions from [this](http://www.testautomationguru.com/jmeter-server-performance-monitoring-with-collectd-influxdb-grafana/) link I am experiencing same issue with following message `Plugin cpu failed to handle option Interval, return code: -1`. Any idea why is this happening?

Comment: I've managed to solve mentioned issue in my previous comment and I've explained it in detail in my answer and I've accepted your answer which help me improve my service unit to work.Please give it a look and vote up if you find it ok. Thanks.  :)

Answer (score 0):

After "experimenting" I managed to reach a solution and make collectd.service run by editing `ExecStart` property in my `/etc/systemd/system/collectd.service` file and now that mentioned file looks like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=statistics collection daemon
Documentation=man:collectd(1)
After=local-fs.target network.target
Requires=local-fs.target network.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/collectd
Restart=always
RestartSec=10
StandardOutput=syslog
StandardError=syslog
Type=notify


[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Changes have been made as @JdeBP suggested in his answer. Also, to specify Interval time of generating metric values for **cpu** plugin I've loaded it as **tag** to specify `Interval` for metrics to be generated every 1s like this:

```
<LoadPlugin cpu> 
   Interval 1
</LoadPlugin cpu>
```

...instead of default format which looks like this: `LoadPlugin cpu`. BTW, plugin loading is specified in `/etc/collectd.conf` file (on **Fedora31** OS). If `Interval` property is specified under ...</plugin cpu> tags then **collectd.service** will NOT start (issue referred at  https://github.com/collectd/collectd/issues/2444). More info at [official Docs](https://collectd.org/documentation/manpages/collectd.conf.5#synopsis), but it's kind of messy and difficult to understand.

Hope that helps if someone gets in this kind of situation. :)
Cheers!